# Getting all records from one table wchich are assigned in other table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a problem with one query using eloquent.
Is there any solution to not write raw SQL?

My tables:

```
blogs: id, name ...

articles: id, name ...

article_tags: blog_id, tag_id

blog_tags: blog_id, tag_id

tags: id, name
```

I want to get all tags wchich are assigned only to blogs (some are the same for articles, but some are only for blogs). How can I do it using Eloquent (is it possible?) in Blog/Tag model?

PS. I am using laravel 5.5

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the relationships properly setup, you can use this:

```
Tag::has('blogs')->doesntHave('articles')->get();
```

Comment: Oh, it was so easy. Thank you! I was looking on it in docs but I don't know why I don't use it...
Anyway - solved!